# I want create a progress bar but percentage is not show in correct way

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular6, ng-bootstrap

I need to create a progress bar that updates some value. So, I created a component.

**percentage (CHILD):**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <p>This progress bar uses the customized default values, but changes the type using an input.</p>
        <p><ngb-progressbar type="warning" [value]="currentValuePercentage" [striped]="true" [animated]="true" #bar><i>{{currentValuePercentage}}%</i></ngb-progressbar></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**the .ts:**

```
currentValuePercentage: number = 0;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes);
    if (changes && changes.currentPercentageIncrement) {
      this.currentValuePercentage = this.currentValuePercentage+Number(changes.currentPercentageIncrement);

    }

  }
```

**FATHER HTML component:**

```
<app-percentage #display_percentage></app-percentage>
```

**FATHER .js:**

```
@ViewChild('display_percentage') display_percentage;
//This is called when my father do some operation and so I need to update percentge
this.display_percentage.ngOnChanges({currentPercentageIncrement:(100/this.listMovimenti.length)});
```

The problem is the percentage is increasing in correct way but the progress bar is not updating in correct way. In details, the progress bar doesn't update but start with 0% and it shows only when the percentage is 100%.

Comment: Use can also use @input